# PHP - Is it possible to open and read shuffle wildcard file in specific path?

Tags: php, file

Example: I need to open shuffle file name one file between `site-1.txt`, `site-2.txt`, `site-3.txt`, `site-more.txt` in folder sites.

How can I write in PHP?

I try

```
$shuffle = file("../sites/site-*.txt");
```

But it’s not a solution to select wildcard file from a specific path as well.

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file()` just reads one file, and returns its contents as an array of lines. The function to find all the files that match a wildcard is `glob()`.

```
$files = glob("../sites/site-*.txt");
```

This returns an array of filenames, and you can then use `array_rand()` to pick one of them.

```
$random_file = $files[array_rand($files)];
```

Comment: Your fingers were just that tiny bit faster!

Comment: @Nick I did the same thing to Jaromanda X in another question :)